# Drawing squares on windows form

Tags: forms, f#

I am trying to draw squares on a form using a list of square objects.

```
let listOfSquares = ResizeArray()

type square(x : float, y : float) =
  let x = x
  let y = y
  let length = 50
  let height = 50
```

I am using a Dropdown menu to create a square on click and then i have another menu button which invalidates the form

```
let square = create.DropDownItems.Add("Square")
let invalidate = file.DropDownItems.Add("Invalidate")
square.Click.Add(fun _ -> listOfSquares.Add(new square(50.0, 50.0)))
invalidate.Click.Add(fun _ -> form.Invalidate())
```

The problem i am having is that the OnPaint method does not draw the squares, however everytime you click on the menu button square it adds to the list.

```
  override form.OnPaint e = 
  let g = e.Graphics
  for square in listOfSquares do
  g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, 300, 150, 48, 48);
```

I tried to manually add values to the list and then run the program like below

```
override form.OnPaint e = 
  listOfSquares.Add(50,50)

  let g = e.Graphics
  for square in listOfSquares do
  g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, 300, 150, 48, 48);
```

Which works, I believe the issue is at the form.invalidate but im quite new to f# i cant find the problem.

Comment: You're never actually using the `square` in your loop in this code..?

Comment: Also, you should indent the body of your for loop (the `g.fillrectangle` should be indented by four more spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to add a way to pull out the properties from your square type.  I'd personally just use a Record here:

```
type Square = { X : int; Y : int; Length : int; Height: int }
```

With this, you're click handler would need to be:

```
square.Click.Add(fun _ -> listOfSquares.Add({ X = 50; Y = 50 ; Width = 50; Height = 50)))
```

Your `OnPaint` method needs to actually draw the squares:

```
override form.OnPaint e = 
  let g = e.Graphics
  for square in listOfSquares do
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, square.X, square.Y, square.Length, square.Height);
```

Note this adds all of the squares at the same location, so they'll be stacked.  You'd, of course, want to change the logic to put them at unique locations each time (change X and Y).

---

Edit:

After further investigation, the problem was actually that there was an additional let binding for `listOfSquares` in the wrong scope, which was causing the event handler to add to the wrong collection.  This meant that the `OnPaint` override was working against a different `ResizeArray` than the event handlers.

Comment: This OnPaint still doesent draw when i click on square.Click and invalidates it. I have tried earlier with a refresh afterwards but it doesent make any difference.

Comment: @user2165793 If you put a breakpoint in there, does it get hit?

Comment: It does hit on line for square in listOfSquares do but not  g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, square.X, square.Y, square.Length, square.Height)

Comment: @user2165793 At that point, what does `listOfSquares.Count` show if you inspect it in locals?

Comment: Not sure if breakpoints works differently in c# or f# but the line (for square in listOfSquares do) breaks on startup and i cant get past it so see if/when it breaks when i click on the invalidate button inside the form. I have another button Count.Click.Add(fun _ -> MessageBox.Show(listOfSquares.Count.ToString())|> ignore ) and it starts at 0 and works intended when i click on square.click.add

Comment: @user2165793 mmm - it should only break when things paint - you should be able to hit F5 to continue, and next paint, it'll break again (ie: after your invalidate)

Comment: Could it be that i have a "do" longer up in the code? And in that case how do i end it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44829/discussion-between-user2165793-and-reed-copsey)